# Is "urgeo inurgor" a correct Latin phrase, meaning "to squeeze the unsqeezable"?

Tags: translation-check, motto

As a tongue-in-cheek joke, I'm trying to make a motto out of Russian phrase "впихнуть невпихуемое", which is literally translated as "to squeeze  unsqueezable". 'Squeeze' being used in this context as 'to forcibly fit something into a tight place'.

This is a more informal version of "put a camel through the eye of a needle", basically.

I don't know a slightest bit of Latin, so tried my best with Wikipedia and came up with this:

> urgeo inurgor

Rationale:

- *urgeo* is something which comes in Google Translate for 'push'/'press'
- *in* as a negative prefix
- taken the stem *urg-* for the second word
- *-or* suffix — one of verb-to-noun suffixes I found in the [Wiki list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Latin_suffixes)

So, question is:
Is this an accurate representation of the above ('to squeeze the unsqueezable')? Or is there a better way to *squeeze* the meaning in?

Comment: FWIW the camel through the eye of a needle is *camelum per foramen acus*. And *to put it* could be *camelum per foramen acus ducere*

Answer (score 7):

*Urgueo/urgeo* does mean "push/press," but it's more in the sense of trying to push forward rather than into something: militarily, rivers against a shore, age against a person as time passes. I don't think it's the right word.

I'm going to offer

> Magna per lacunas ponenda parvas.

as a motto. A literal translation would be something like, "Large things must be put through small gaps." Latin has a pretty free word order, and putting *magna* ("large") first and *parvas* ("small") last creates a nice balance that's characteristic of mottos and aphorisms.

Comment: How about *instringibilia interstringere* to make it more of a wordplay? [_Interstringo_ is attested](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=interstringo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059); _*instringibilis_ seems like a natural construction

Comment: Well, it's attested, but it means "strangle" or "throttle," so I'm not sure it's what the OP is looking for. :)

Comment: It also means _to squeeze tight_, or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Hmm. Possibly it means that post-classically. I looked in a few places and found it in contexts where "squeeze tight" didn't make sense as a translation, but that doesn't mean it's not an option. I think, though, that even if it does mean that, *inter* probably indicates "between two hands" rather than "into something."

Comment: @Rafael I know it's been about a year and a half, but your suggestion would still make a fine answer.

Comment: @Rafael Four years later, I know, but you still should make that an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, four years later, at cmw's and Joonas' request, I propose,

> **instrinxibilia interstringere**

Note that the first word isn't actually attested, but sounds like a natural construction of **[in–](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in-#Latin) + [strinxi](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dstringo) + [–bilis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-bilis)** for unsqueezable. Here, the verb **stringo** means *to draw tight, to bind or tie tight; to draw, bind, or press together*. From that, **instrinxibilia** is a regular plural neuter, to mean *the unsqueezable* or just *unsqueezable things*.

The verb **[interstringo, -ere](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=interstringo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)**, in turn, is attested and means *to squeeze tight*.

Comment: Haha, you finally did it!

Comment: Shouldn't it be *instringibilia* (as in your original suggestion)?